# JavaMail does not detect invalid email address of receiver(address that does not exist)

Tags: jakarta-mail, sendmail, email-validation

I'm developing a web app that needs to send reminders to the customers. I'm using JavaMail for the same.but when I provide invalid receivers email address (email id that does not exist) the program ***does not throw*** `SendFailedException`. ***but inbox of the sender email id contains delivery report saying mail sending failed. Is there any way to detect this failure in the program***? The code used is as follows:

[note that gmail smpt is used]

```
 Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("mail.smtp.host", "smtp.gmail.com");
        props.put("mail.stmp.user", "abc@gmail.com");          
        //If you want you use TLS 
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

        props.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.password", "password");
        // If you want to use SSL
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.port", "465");
        props.put("mail.smtp.socketFactory.class",
                   "javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory");
        props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
        props.put("mail.smtp.port", "465");
        Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, new Authenticator() {
            @Override
            protected PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
                String username = "abc@gmail.com";
                String password = "password";
                return new PasswordAuthentication(username,password); 
            }
        });
        String[] to = {"test1@gmail.com","test2@yahoo.in","test3@gmail.com","test4@gmail.com"};
        String from = "abc@gmail.com";
        String subject = "Testing...";
        MimeMessage msg = new MimeMessage(session);
        try {
            msg.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
            InternetAddress[] addressTo = new InternetAddress[to.length];
            for (int i = 0; i < to.length; i++)
            {
                addressTo[i] = new InternetAddress(to[i]);
            }
            msg.setRecipients(RecipientType.TO, addressTo); 
            // msg.setRecipient(MimeMessage.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
            msg.setSubject(subject);
            // msg.setText("JAVA is the BEST");

            // Create the message part 
            BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();

            // Fill the message
            messageBodyPart.setText("This is message body");

            // Create a multipar message
            Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();

            // Set text message part
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Part two is attachment
            messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
            String filename = "file.txt";
            DataSource source = new FileDataSource(filename);
            messageBodyPart.setDataHandler(new DataHandler(source));
            messageBodyPart.setFileName(filename);
            multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);

            // Send the complete message parts
            msg.setContent(multipart );

            Transport transport = session.getTransport("smtp");
            transport.send(msg);
            System.out.println("E-mail sent !");
        }
        catch(Exception exc) {
            System.out.println(exc);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may have misunderstood [how "store and forward" works for email](http://osdir.com/ml/java.sun.javamail.general/2005-04/msg00003.html): only very rarely will the sender immediately know that the address is invalid. This would most likely be the case for an invalid domain name, but even then you don't have any guarantees that your SMTP-session will report the error, since it depends on how the MTA you're delivering to handles email.